# Post values in HTMLforms without using TwebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Without TWebBrowser input values in form on Button Click and get next webpage response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499991/without-twebbrowser-input-values-in-form-on-button-click-and-get-next-webpage-re)

We are working with Delphi Xe2 and Indy 10 components.

We need to input the values in HTML page and click search button and get next result web page without using TWebBrowser. When We post the parameters on the [URL](https://sun.sunexpress.com.tr/web/RezvEntry.xhtml?LANGUAGE=EN), I am unable to get the result webpage.

On Post, we get the current page HTML code. How could we get the result web page in response?

Code we are using:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  aStream  : TStringStream;
  data         : TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  aStream  := TStringStream.Create;
  data     := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    with IdHTTP1 do
    begin
      data.AddFormField('DEP_PORT', 'Basel');
      data.AddFormField('ARR_PORT', 'Gaziantep');
      Request.UserAgent      := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0';
      Request.AcceptLanguage  := 'en-US,en;q=0.5';
      Request.Connection         :=  'keep-alive';
      Request.Accept                := 'text/html';
      IOHandler     := SSL;
      try
        Post('https://sun.sunexpress.com.tr/web/RezvEntry.xhtml?LANGUAGE=EN', data, aStream);
      except
      on E: Exception do
        showmessage('Error encountered during POST: ' + E.Message);
      end;
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(aStream.DataString);

  except
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The web site you are referring to also adds a jsessionid to the post-url. Maybe you cannot post without a valid jsessionid?

Comment: That's the cookie, but there's [`much more to add`](http://i.imgur.com/iHI9Ref.jpg) to the form data. I haven't tried the code from the question, but (even if assuming a proper SSL configuration) I wouldn't expect from flight reservation system to fetch me some sensible results by entering just departure and arrival destinations.

Comment: thanks birger and TLama,sorry for post duplicate. But we are not getting the response. Is there no way to post data.?